# Linq query dynamic where double

Tags: linq, dynamic, double, where-clause

I have the next IQueryable which filter a Double value:

```
var pQuery =
        (from c in db.TABLE
         select new
             {
                cDate = c.DATE,
                dMid = (double)c.MID,
             })
             .Where("dMid > 13.5");
```

When I see the IntelliTrace, Linq generate the next query:

```
select DATE, MID
from TABLE
where MID > cast(135 as float(53))
```

I don't why Linq delete decimal separator and convert the filter expression from 13.5 to 135.

Someone can help me???

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't use the strongly-typed `where c.MID > 13.5f`, but maybe your problem has something to do with your culture settings (i.e. it's interpreting the decimal point as a thousands-separator)?

Comment: try the `decimal` or `float` instead of `double`

Comment: It's a dynamic filter, so I need to use Linq Dymnamic. I have the same problem with ",", convert 13,5 to 135.

Answer (score 0):

And the end it was easier than I thought. User lc. gives me the solution using "f" character

```
var pQuery =
    (from c in db.TABLE
     select new
         {
            cDate = c.DATE,
            dMid = (double)c.MID,
         })
         .Where("dMid > 13.5f");
```

.. and this is translated to:

```
select DATE, MID
from TABLE
where MID > cast(13.5 as float(53))
```